# How to use position sticky for horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-position, sticky

I need to scroll table according to X axis. My code looks like this.
I tried also position fixeb but for some reason it scroll work only on Y axis.
What I am doing wrong?

**HTML**

```css
table {
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
table,
th,
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,
td {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
th {
    font-weight: 700;
    position: sticky;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Some header</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        ...
        <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Some header</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        ...
        <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <table></table>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need the sticky on the first column:

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 400px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

table {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

td:first-of-type {
  background-color: #eee;
  position: sticky;
  left: -1px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Some header</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Some header</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

The solution's from a post on [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/idea-simple-responsive-spreadsheet/).